# How to embed Play 2.6 using Akka HTTP Server?

Tags: scala, playframework

Play 2.5 used Netty as default and allowed easy embedding. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaEmbeddingPlay

How is this now done with Akka HTTP Server, which is now the default server backend?

The page https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaEmbeddingPlay is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation was split in two pages:

1. For Akka HTTP Server: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.1/ScalaEmbeddingPlayAkkaHttp
2. For Netty Server: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.1/ScalaEmbeddingPlayNetty

You should use `AkkaHttpServerComponents` to avoid deprecated APIs:

```
import play.api.{ BuiltInComponents, NoHttpFiltersComponents }
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerComponents

val server = new AkkaHttpServerComponents with BuiltInComponents with NoHttpFiltersComponents {

  // To avoid using the deprecated Action builder while
  // keeping the `Action` idiom.
  private val Action = defaultActionBuilder

  override def router: Router = Router.from {
    case GET(p"") => Action {
      Results.Ok("Hello, World")
    }
  }


}.server
```

Comment: The sbt dependency for this is ```"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-akka-http-server" % playVersion```